$T_2$ countably paracompact spaces
Knowing that $T_2$ paracompact spaces are fully $T_4$, I was wondering about what would happen if the space was countably paracompact instead of paracompact. I looked for spaces that are $T_2$ and countably paracompact, but that don't verfiy certain stronger separation axioms, and I have found an example of a $T_2$ countably paracompact space that isn't regular (altered long ray). However, I haven't found any example that isn't $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$, in fact, neither functionally $T_2$. I wanted to ask if anyone knows an example of a $T_2$ countably paracompact space that isn't $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$.

Clearly every countably compact space is countably paracompact.
On the other hand, Tzannes has produced a countably compact Hausdorff space $X$ on which every continuous real-valued function is constant:

V.Tzannes, A Hausdorff countably compact space on which every continuous real-valued
function is constant, Topology Proc., 21 (1996), 239-244.

Clearly Tzannes's space cannot be $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ (i.e. functionally Hausdorff). Neither is the space regular, first-countable, or separable (loc. cit.).
In fact, Tzannes shows that no pair of distinct points of $X$ have disjoint closed neigbourhoods! Thus the space is not even Urysohn.
Thanks to @Ulli for pointing this last fact out!
Edit: the following is from my original answer. It gives a construction that produces Hausdorff, non-Uysohn spaces from Hausdorff, non-regular spaces.
Here, to be clear, I use the symbol $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ to denote the functionally Hausdorff axiom: every two points are functionally separated. Many authors use $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ to denote the Urysohn property: each pair of points have disjoint, closed neighourhoods. Every functionally Hausdorff space is Urysohn, and every Urysohn space is Hausdorff.
I̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶k̶n̶o̶w̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶T̶z̶a̶n̶n̶e̶s̶'̶s̶ ̶s̶p̶a̶c̶e̶ ̶$̶X̶$̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶U̶r̶y̶s̶o̶h̶n̶, so consider the following. Since $X$ is not regular there is $A\subseteq X$ such that
$$\overline A\neq \widehat{\overline A}:=\bigcap\{\overline U\mid U\;\text{open},\; A\subseteq U\}.$$
Define $Y$ to be the adjunction space
$$Y=X\cup_{\overline A}X.$$
It's easy to see that $Y$ is Hausdorff. Moreover, $Y$ is countably compact, since it is the continuous image of the sum $X\sqcup X$. In particular, $Y$ is countably paracompact.
On the other hand, fix a point
$$x\in \widehat{\overline A}\setminus \overline A.$$
There are two distinct points $y_1,y_2\in Y$ corresponding to $x$. Since each closed neighbourhood of $x$ contains points of $A$, the points $y_1,y_2$ have no closed disjoint neighbourhoods in $Y$.
Thus $Y$ is a countably compact Hausdorff space which is not Urysohn.

In the abstract, Tzannes says that his space is not Urysohn.

The abstract? That would be the last place I would look!

Well, this was the first place, I looked at ;-). But it appears also in the text part, actually, twice.

I (still) haven't checked your construction, but what I understood is that given a Hausdorff, countably compact, non-regular space $X$, it gives a Hausdorff, countably compact, non-Urysohn space $Y$, and this construction is fairly easy, in fact a standard operation. But this would then give a lot easier example than the one of Tzannes: just take the very simple Hausdorff, countably compact, non-regular topology on
$\omega_1+1$ as in Engelking, General topology, 3.10.B.

Thank you for your answer, Tyrone. And, thank you for your comment, Ulli.

Before seeing the Tzannes paper, I wondered, whether one could find an example on $\omega_1$, which is coarser than the order topology, hence automatically countably compact.
I doubt that the space of Tzannes has a finer topology homeomorphic to the order topology on $\omega_1$.
But Corollary 5.4 in this paper gives a definite example. In particular, it provides (most likely different) examples to the PO's question.

So I believe the space you are looking for is the Golomb space (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression_topologies) That is $\mathbb{Z^+}$ with the topology generated by the sets of the form:
\begin{equation*}
N_{a,b}=\{a+b\cdot k: k\in \mathbb{N}\}
\end{equation*}
where $gcd(a,b)=1$.
This is a second countable space so it will be countably paracompact and is easy to verify that it is $T_2$ and that the sets $N_{a,b}$ form a basis. We show that we cannot separate two distinct points by closed subsets. We note that $\overline{N_{a,b}}$ will contain $\{b\cdot k:k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ which proves that no two closed neighborhoods can be disjoint. Given a point $b k$ and a neighborhood which without loss of generality will be of the form $N_{bk,c}$ such that $gcd(bk,c)=1$ and in particular $gcd(b,c)=1$. Consider the case where $a<bk$.  By Bezout let $m$ and $n$ be integers such that $m$ is positive and $mb+n c=bk-a$. Rearranging have that $a+m b=bk-nc\in N_{a,b}\cap N_{bk,c}$. The case where $bk<a$ is analogous. This proves that the Golomb space is not $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$.
Note that the Golomb space is also a great example of a countable $T_2$ space that is Edit: Connected.

@Ulli yes of course!!

Are you sure that it is countably paracompact? Second countable implies Lindelöf; Lindelöf and countably paracompact implies paracompact; and $T_2$ and paracompact implies $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$.

@Almanzoris is countable paracompactness, paracompactness for countable coverings or that every covering has a locally countable refinement?

I should have defined the properties in my question, my bad. I meant paracompactness for countable coverings.

Then yes, the Golomb space is not going to be countably paracompact.

Still, thank you for your answer, Giorgio. I have learnt from it too.
